# Decryption in nodejs fails if the encrypted text contains '+'

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I have encrypted data (Encrypted using aes256 in .NET) that I am trying to decrypt in NodeJs.

The decryption is failing if the encrypted text has '+' in it. I am using AES 256 with Padding zero while encrypting.

```
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-256-CBC', Buffer.from(key), Buffer.from(iv));
  decipher.setAutoPadding(false);

   var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-256-CBC', Buffer.from(key), Buffer.from(iv));
   var decrypted=decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');
   decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
```

This works fine if the ecrypted data does not have + in it.

How can I decrypt such data?

EX: `Ytjf6RvQglvYIqS1sDRPREm0DCF+ZM5ykzHYpxTt+4Y=`

Comment: Have you verified the `encrypted` actually has a `+` in it at this point, and that you haven't accidentally urldecoded it earlier in the program, such that it now has a space in it?

Comment: Are there any particular errors that you get? Sorry, deleted answer, forgot you had an example, and it decoded to 64 bytes, which is a multiple of 16, the block size of AES.

Comment: Make that 32 bytes, 64 in hex. Sorry, long day.

Comment: @RobNapier yes the encrypted actually has the  sign. Decrypted it successfully in .NET but need to do the same in Nodejs.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I am getting the following error `Error: error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length`

Comment: First, note that you're defining `decipher` twice here, once where you turn off padding, and once where you don't (and that' the one you use). This error suggests that this is not your actual code, however. Can you show this failing in a self-contained example (with a key, iv, and encrypted all provided)? I cannot reproduce this problem using your code. I still suspect that the "encrypted" that you're showing here is not precisely the value of "encrypted" in your program. This error strongly suggests that they're different.

Comment: @RobNapier The string is encrypte in .NET and trying to decrypt it in nodejs. The `+` in the encrypted is being replaced by a space in the nodejs and it is decrypting a part of the string (until it encounters space i guess) and at `final()` it is failing with the above error.

Comment: Isn't that what I said before? Somewhere you're replacing `+` with "space" before you get to this point. You need to not do that. I suspect if you `console.log(encrypted)` immediately before you called update(), it'd have a space in it, right?

Comment: Yes. It is a service call and as soon as I read the req the input is replaced with string `req.query.cipher;` here itself it is converted to space. Not sure how I can stop that from happening!

Comment: Convert your base64 to base64url. You can of course also URL-escape your base64, but then you'd get an unknown number of escapes, so it is less efficient and less predictable.